# Id base selector jquery click event not working in Single page application

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with single page application, trying simple click event, its working with first screen but not working with second or third screen...

```
   $("#Signup").click(function() {
          alert("click success");
        $("#ButtonAction1").modal({
            show: true
     });

    });
```

Comment: do you have elements on different pages of a spa with the same id? don't do that

Comment: Can you provide some html or jsfiddle. Could be a delegation issue with dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

You must not use the same ID for different elements in the same page, use classes instead.

Comment: This should be a comment. OP hasn't mentioned anything about multiple IDs

Comment: Ok, he said he used that code to show different elements, so maybe he is using the same ID in all those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your DOM is already fully loaded.

```
$(function() { 
  $("#Signup").click(function() {
    alert("click success");
    $("#ButtonAction1").modal({
        show: true
    });
 });
});
```

If you add an element after the click event handler has been added, the element won't inherit it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the on instead of the click since it works with dynamic elements and delegates the events.

You can check out the difference between the methods here [Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)

```
 $("#Signup").on('click',function() {
        alert("click success");
        $("#ButtonAction1").modal({
            show: true
         });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're buttons are dynamically loaded. You can use the following:

```
$('document').on('click', '#Signup', 
  function(){
    alert("click success");
    $("#ButtonAction1").modal({
      show: true
    });
  }
);
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16898442/6671505

```
$('#PARENT').on('click', '#DYNAMICALLY_ADDED_CHILD', function(){ CODE HERE });
```